# $locationProvider html5mode causing "cannot GET" error on refresh - AngularJS Node app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, .htaccess

I am trying to remove the hashtags from my Angularjs app's URLs using the locationProvider, and it works well until I refresh a page manually. This always causes a "cannot GET .." error in the browser. I have done some research and I think I have to use an .htaccess file to redirect, but I am not sure how to implement it and I have searched the web for a solution but no luck so far.

Here is my app.js which handles routing to my Angular views and controllers:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
    myApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/', { 
                templateUrl: 'views/partials/play.html',
                controller: 'playCtrl'
            }).
            when('/dictionary', {
                templateUrl: 'views/partials/dictionary.html', 
                controller: 'dictionaryCtrl'
            }).
            when('/add', {
                templateUrl: 'views/partials/word.html', 
                controller: 'wordCtrl'
            }).
            when('/about', {
                templateUrl: 'views/partials/about.html', 
                controller: 'aboutCtrl'
            }).

            otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});

        // use the HTML5 History API
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
})();
```

And I have also added this inside the `<head>` in my index.html:

```
<base href="/">
```

The app is built using Node.js, Express, Angular & Mongodb if this helps.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case some one else is wondering you need to redirect all routes that Node is not using to Angular:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile('./path/to/index.html')
})
```

This has to be done in server.js. Don't forget to use ./ in the sendfile link :)

Comment: It would be nicve to see a generic solution for **angular**, not one specifically targeting angular using a node,js backend and express ...

Answer (score 1):

It depends on Angular version.

Latest `Angular` versions require following options:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: true,
  requireBase: false
});
```

> If you configure $location to use html5Mode (history.pushState), you
>   need to specify the base URL for the application with a 
>   tag or configure $locationProvider to not require a base tag by
>   passing a definition object with `requireBase:false` to
>   `$locationProvider.html5Mode()`

Mode details from official documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase)

So all you need is to handle every route you described in angular on the server-side and render the same (probably index) page with angular plugged in.

Comment: This doesn't work for me i'm afraid. When refreshing the homepage, it is fine, but any other page such as /add or /dictionary, I get the error. ONLY on refresh, from a link in the header the URL still works fine

Comment: @OllyBarca seems you don't have proper routing on your backend. You should take care your server responds on all these requests and renders the main page with angular itself.

Comment: I have routes in my backend but only to handle API calls. I have this "app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));" to load the index.html in my server.js

Comment: @OllyBarca `express.static` is for static files, api calls are also good, but you also need to have a bunch of routes which renders index page (where angular is located).

Comment: Ok, what is the best way to do that? with an .htaccess file? I heard rumours that all I have to do it route the user through index.html every time.

Comment: @OllyBarca simply add relevant routes to your nodejs application which render the same page with angular.js.

Comment: Like res.render(template)...? I will give it a try, thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. I put a fallback route at the end of my express app and it fixed the problem. Feel free to add your answer and I will mark it as accepted.