# Removing # from url of angularJS for SEO with backend as Django

Tags: angularjs, django, seo

I know removing hash from AngularJS is pretty straightforward but the problem is that the backend is in Django.

So, the app works unless the page is refreshed using "F5".

so, `http://127.0.0.1:8000/account` works if the button is clicked but refreshing the page gives me `Page not found` as the server searches for it in `urls.py` file

Can someone please suggest me any fix for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is right. When you refresh the page, firstly request gets processed on the server (and goes to django router). So server should know that it should return your angular page for this URL.

Let's assume that your page that contains Angular application lives on view called `index`. Then just point this url to it:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^account/$', index), 
]
```

or point all urls to  your view (in case you don't need any other url's to be processed without angular):

```
//something like this, not really sure about the regex
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^.*$', index), 
]
```

or something like

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^/account/.*$', index), 
]
```

You're not alone with this issue: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31647175/6805304) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42842014/6805304).
So as you can see, it's not Django-specific trouble, but some general client-server workflow.

Answer (score 0):

Use Locationprovider instead of routeProvider and enable html5 to true.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider