# angular otherwise not working with spring boot

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-boot

I am facing some weird type of behavior with spring boot + angular js while doing routing. Although routing is working but otherwise redirect to is not working.

For example:

- if the url is http://localhost/admin/home#/analysis(working)
- if the url is http://localhost/admin/home#/ (working)
- but if the url is http://localhost/admin/home  (not working)

I have configured otherwise but its not doing any benefit

Below is my code:

```
 .config(['$routeProvider','$httpProvider',function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/analysis', {
        templateUrl : '../resources/views/includes/dashboard.html',
        controller : "RegistrationController"
    }).when('/', {
        templateUrl : '../resources/views/includes/profile.html',
        controller : "RegistrationController"
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
     $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
}]);
```

I have placed      in html

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to take a look at `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`.

It tells angularJS to use HTML5 strategy if available. Basically `#` is required for those browsers who do not support HTML5.

Also, you will be required to configure `<base>` tag of html.

Even when you will implement these concepts, you will stumble across another issue which I faced as well. If you navigate via `href` in the application, it would work , but if you copy the `url` and paste it directly in the browser, you'll get error as it would directly hit the server and will try to find necessary URL mapping on the server.

For more details, you can look at this [this question which I asked for this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47373927/removing-from-url-of-angularjs-for-seo-with-backend-as-django)

I hope it'll help.

Comment: Correct by doing this we can never redirect directly on copy paste or on refreshing the browser

Comment: @Hara : It can be done by configuring the server side conf.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is more related to SEO-related AngularJS implementation, basically, the solution to this is using the `rewrite` functionality of Apache or Nginx.

For more information, you can start [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-seo-with-prerender-io).