# Url Not found on reload + Angular5

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, angular5

I am facing one issue related to the angular app, using components in my app then when I go with the single page the page loaded successfully but when I open that URL in a new tab or reload it, give error Not found.

I am using AWS apache server for this and only facing this issue on it, in my Godaddy server page reloading working properly.

Here I am attaching my screenshot of the error.[[image: Error}[1]]

Thankx in advance

Comment: You can possibly find the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47373927/removing-from-url-of-angularjs-for-seo-with-backend-as-django . After refresh, ur server is not able to resolve the url as its being generated by `angular` not the server

Comment: Thankx for a quick response, Could you please explain more in which file this code will be applied?

Comment: I think you need to check for `config` file for `apache server`. You might need to redirect certain `url` patterns. I would suggest you to google it out for AWS apache server and update your question with your finding. I'll try to pick it up from there as I am also not much aware of this conf file.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml

Comment: @ShashankVivek thanks, I already tried this but not finding a solution.

Answer (score 6):

I think your .htaccess file is not reachable,

Create .htaccess file inside /var/www/html i.e. in the folder where your index.html is.

**Put following code in it:-**

```
RewriteEngine On
    # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Than goto /etc/apache2 folder and open apache2.conf file with sudo.

```
cd /etc/apache2
sudo vim apache2.conf
```

Remove comment(#) of AccessFileName it will look like

```
AccessFileName .htaccess
```

Then find the line where there is

```
<Directory /var/www/>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride None
     Require all granted
</Directory>
```

replace "None" with "All"

```
AllowOverride All
```

Done!

Now run command

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

And check now!

Comment: In my case, adding of .htaccess file as shown above was enough to prevent site from crashing. So direct server configuration may not be needed (if server is preconfigured, of course).

Answer (score 3):

Add .htaccess file in your project root folder.
bellow code add in your **Appache .htaccess** file:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

Nginx .conf file :

```
location / {
  if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.html break;
  }
}
```

execute command :

`sudo a2enmod rewrite`

`sudo service apache2 restart`