# After Removeing # From angularjs with Codeigniter website URL ,then if reload then its give 404 page not found...(main Error for page not reload)?

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter-3

After Removeing # From angularjs with Codeigniter website URL ,then html is not load properly in main ng-view.(main Error for page not reload)
What should i do for overcome this problem.

```
var app = angular.module('main-App', ['ngRoute','angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);
app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',
function ($routeProvider,$locationProvider) { 
    $routeProvider.
            when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
                controller: 'AdminController'
            }).
            when('/items', {
                templateUrl: 'templates/items.html',
                controller: 'ItemController'
            }).
            when('/users', {
                templateUrl: 'templates/user_view.html',
                controller: 'ItemController'
            }).
            when('/wearhouse',{
                templateUrl:'templates/wearhouse_view.html',
                controller:'ItemController'
            }).
            when('/units',{
                templateUrl:'templates/units_view.html',
                controller:'ItemController'
            }).
             when('/product',{
                templateUrl:'templates/product_view.html',
                controller:'ItemController'
            }).
             when('/productListing',{
                templateUrl:'templates/product_listing_view.html',
                controller:'ItemController'
            }).
            when('/stock',{
                templateUrl:'templates/stoke_view.html',
                controller:'ItemController' 
            }).
            otherwise(
            {redirectTo : '/'}
            );

             $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }]);
```

.htaccess file in codeigniter:-

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Have you added `<base href="/">` into html?

Comment: yes i am add <base href="/">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its is happening because when you remove `hash` from your url, your server tries to `map` the entire `url` and then provide the data to client.

When you have `#` in your url, the server ignores whatever comes after `#` and simply maps the path which is there before `#`

> For: `www.something.com\resoucePath\#abc\def`

server simply ignores `abc\def` and this is how `angularJS` exploits routing.

> Where as for : `www.something.com\resoucePath\abc\def`

server goes ahead and find `url` mapping or `@path` matching `\abc` and then `\def`

You need to configure your server to handle such requests. I has the same issue once, [this link will surely help you get some idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47373927/removing-from-url-of-angularjs-for-seo-with-backend-as-django)